# Django Rest Framework: How to associate the object with the user when posting the object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to creating REST API so I might misunderstand something.
I'm creating REST API using Django Rest Framework. And I'm trying to create an object and send it from my mobile app.

However, API returns 400. I think it still cannot associate the object with the request user and I'm wondering how to do it.

`models.py`

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('item_name', 'created_by')
```

and `views.py`

```
class ListItems(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

What I want to know is how to associate the object with the request user when posting the object like as we do like

```
if form.is_valid():
    item = form.save(commit=False)
    item.created_by = request.user
    item.save()
```

Comment: `if form.is_valid():` - where is this code placed. In views? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @Headmaster I mean I wanted to ask how to do it in `django-rest-framework`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is like this:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

 created_by = serializers.HiddenField(
    default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)
```

Reference can be found [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault)

Answer (score 2):

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('item_name',)

class ListItems(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

## you can do this way

Comment: Questioner getting `400` which is for `required-field` , i suppose that is `created_by` is not passing to the serializer. So this is actually won't come from here, validation error will rise before it.

Comment: remove created_by from fields = ('item_name', 'created_by') in serializer

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible way to overwrite `serializer_create` method. As `user` is not associated with request.data first we need to make sure, this is write_only field and also need to assign current user from modelSerializer's `self.context.request.user`. Following addition should solve the problem.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('item_name', 'created_by')
        extra_kwargs = {'created_by': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        item = Item(
            item_name=validated_data['item_name'],
            created_by=self.context.request.user
        )

        item.save()
        return item
```

Reference [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

`models.py`

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField('Category', max_length=200, unique=True, help_text='Name of the category')
   slug = models.SlugField('Slug', max_length=100, db_index=True, unique=True, help_text='Name of the category in format URL')

   def __str__(self):
       return (self.name)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.slug = slugify(self.name)     
       super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`serializers.py`

```
 class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = Category
       fields = [
           'id', 'name', 'slug'
       ]
       read_only_fields = [
          'slug', 
       ]
```

Finally, I get the user in the view, before to save the post.

`views.py`

```
class CategoryList(APIView):te a new category instance.

   permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

   def get(self, request, format=None):
       categories = Category.objects.all()
       serializer = CategorySerializer(categories, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

   def post(self, request, format=None):
       serializer = CategorySerializer(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
           Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```